# Making animation of a straight line

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, animations

How can I make an animation of line y=-3 that rotates by angle $\phi$ and the perpendicular distance from origin to this line. I also need to trace the shape that points of the intersection of the line with the perpendicular line makes.

Sorry, I forgot to mention that I also need a coordinate axes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot,pst-eucl,multido}

\begin{document}
\multido{\iA=0+6,\iB=1+1}{60}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-5.2,-5.2)(5.5,2.5)
    \pnode(0,0){O}
    \psaxes[linewidth=0.5pt]{->}(0,0)(-5,-5)(5,2)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \rput{\iA}(0,-3){\pnodes(-4,0){A}(4,0){B}\psline(A)(B)}
    \pnode(!\iA\space tan dup 0 eq { -3 0 }{1 exch div neg 5 mul 5} ifelse exch){C}
    \pstInterLL{A}{B}{O}{C}{D}
    \pnode(0,0){Aa}
    \multido{\iC=0+6}{\iB}{%
      \rput{\iC}(0,-3){\pnodes(-4,0){Ab}(4,0){Bb}}%
      \pnode(!\iC\space tan dup 0 eq { -3 0 }{1 exch div neg 5 mul 5} ifelse exch){Cb}%
      \pstInterLL[PointSymbol=none,PointName=none]{Ab}{Bb}{O}{Cb}{Db}%
      \psline(Aa)(Db)\pnode(Db){Aa}}%
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](0,0)(D)
\end{pspicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

Converted into a `gif` with:

```
convert -delay 50 -loop 0 -density 200 -scale 350 -alpha remove test.pdf test.gif
```

[image]

Comment: I also need a coordinate axis.

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: This is line y=0, can you please change it to y=-3. and there is no perpendicular line from origin to the line in your solution.

Comment: @Student: Which is the rotation point of the line?

Comment: line y=-3, and the rotation point is (0,-3). Thanks.

Comment: Ah ok, I misunderstood ... See again the edited answer

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks heaps Herbert.